# Why is the plan different when using sp_executesql (parameterized) vs. ad-hoc, even when the plan cache is empty?

Tags: sql-server

I am using the same query in both cases, except that I turn variables used in the ad hoc case into parameters that I pass in when using sp_executesql.  I was originally under the impression that the only difference in plans would be if sp_executesql re-used a plan already in the cache.  However, what I found was that the plans can differ even when the plan cache is empty.

Further testing seemed to show that while sp_executesql uses parameter sniffing (choosing the best plan based on the specific parameters given), the ad hoc query did not.  I came to this conclusion because the tested 2 versions of the ad hoc case: 1 normal and 1 where I use OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN on all the variables, and the plans were identical in the several cases that I tried.

Can anyone confirm that this is indeed the case, that ad hoc queries do not optimize based on variable values the way that sp_executesql does with parameters?